# Step Through (Debug) PHP Code in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I have an application I'm working on in which I make many AJAX calls to external PHP files. These PHP files get certain parameters, connect to the DB, and perform a task with them.

I just recently started using Netbeans for an IDE and love it thus far. However, whenever I put a breakpoint on one of my external PHP files (the ones I'm making AJAX requests to) and attempt to run the debugger, my breakpoints are never hit. Am I doing something wrong? Or does the Netbeans debugger not stop on the breakpoints of external files you are referencing?

Comment: Sanity check: did you configure NB to use xdebug?

Comment: No! I guess I assumed it would be configured when I installed NB. I'm sort of a newbie with all this :-)

Comment: Here's your tutorial then: http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug ;)

Comment: Awesome! Just edited my php.ini file and it's now stepping through my code! Thanks Mchl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NetBeans need to be configured to use xdebug, before you can strt debugging. For instructions on installing and configuring xdebug see here: http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug

Comment: Thanks a million! Quick question - when I Run with Debugging, the debugger pauses at the beginning of each different file the application uses. Is there a way to auto-run through all my code up until it reaches the breakpoint?

Comment: I'm not sure about that one. You'd need to check xdebug docs I suppose.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks for the quick & easy answer to my main question!

Comment: Just found the answer to my smaller question. For anyone wondering: to stop the debugger from pausing on the first line of each file, go to Tools >> Options >> PHP >> Debugging and uncheck the Stop at First Line option

Answer (score 3):

Here is a nice step-by-step tutorial for setting this up.  A little less wordy than the netbeans documentation:

http://arturito.net/2011/05/21/local-and-remote-php-debuging-in-netbeans-with-xdebug-on-google-chrome-just-like-in-visual-studio/

Comment: Perfect conlusion! A "_little less wordy_", LOL! :] When I saw Netbeans docs I thought: "_What? They expect me to read all this blah, blah, blah over few pages to debug with Xdebug?_"...